# How to resolve refactoring done in Xcode with Mercurial

Tags: xcode, mercurial, refactoring

I have some files I started to refactor in an iOS project. I did the refactoring through Xcode and when I ran "hg status" it shows a bunch of new and deleted files (as expected). What I'm trying to figure out is the best way to go about resolving this and letting Mercurial know of the changes. Is there a command I can use to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hg addremove` is your friend. You can get more information [here](http://hgtip.com/tips/advanced/2009-09-30-detecting-renames-automatically/) and by running `hg help addremove`

Comment: Importantly, modern `hg addremove` will detect rename files and record them as a `hg remove old new` instead of just `hg forget old; hg add new`. This is import for future merges. By default it only detects renames with no modifications — use the `--similary` setting to make it detect renames even if the renamed files have been edited slightly.